# Use str_replace for the string "/\/\" in PHP

Tags: php

How do I change these codes using PHP code ...

I tried this but failed.

```
$str = str_replace(
array('A','/\'),
array('M','/\/\'),
array('N','/\/'),
array('V','\/'),
array('W','\/\/'),
$html);
```

What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: What you are trying to change ?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar Of course the letters `A, M, N, V, W`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes. Also, you are not forming the parameters to [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) correctly, they should be an array of strings and an array of replacements. This will do what you want:

```
$html = 'MAVEN WAR';
$str = str_replace(array('A', 'M', 'N', 'V', 'W'), 
                   array('/\\','/\\/\\','/\\/','\\/','\\/\\/'), 
                   $html);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
/\/\/\\/E/\/ \/\//\R
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6WsNi)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using the `str_replace` is

```
$string = "ABCD This";
$pattern = ['A','B','C','D'];
$replacments = ['1A','2B','3C','4D'];
echo str_replace($pattern, $replacments, $string);
```